# Aspect Oriented Programming in Spring error when I implements interface

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I'm studying Aspect Oriented Programming in Spring with @AspectJ
I write an example but when I run it I've an error
Here are the class that I write

```
    package concert;

/**
 *
 * @author phate
 */
public interface Performance {
    public void perform();
}
```

Class PerformanceImpl implements the Performance interface and implements perform method

```
package concert;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

/**
 *
 * @author Dennis A. Boanini
 */
@Service
public class PerformanceImpl implements Performance{

    @Override
    public void perform() {
        System.out.println("perform");
    }

}
```

Class Audience is annotated with @Aspect and declare some Advice

```
package concert;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 *
 * @author Dennis A. Boanini
 */
@Component
@Aspect
public class Audience {

    @Before("execution(* concert.Performance.perform(..))")
    public void silenceCellPhones(){
        System.out.println("Silencing cell phones");
    }

    @Before("execution(* concert.Performance.perform(..))")
    public void takeSeats(){
        System.out.println("Taking seats");
    }

    @AfterReturning("execution(* concert.Performance.perform(..))")
    public void applause(){
        System.out.println("CLAP CLAP CLAP");
    }

    @AfterThrowing("execution(* concert.Performance.perform(..))")
    public void demandRefund(){
        System.out.println("Demanding a refund");
    }
}
```

Class ConcertConfig is the bean that autoproxy

```
package concert;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

/**
 *
 * @author Dennis A. Boanini
 */
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan
public class ConcertConfig{

    @Bean
    public Audience audience() {
        return new Audience();
    }
}
```

And this is the main class

```
public class Turing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(ConcertConfig.class);
        ctx.refresh();
        Performance userService = ctx.getBean(PerformanceImpl.class);
        userService.perform();

    }
}
```

If I run I receive this error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [concert.PerformanceImpl] is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1088)
    at com.phate.spring.aop.example.Turing.main(Turing.java:32)
```

But if I eliminate the interface everything work correctly, why?

Comment: What happens if you get a bean by `Performance.class`? Try assigning a name with `@Service("something")` and then try to get it by name.

Comment: Works! Thank you so much!

Comment: Which one works, `Performance.class` or assigning name? I would like to know.

Comment: both would work and it would also work if `proxy-target-class=true` would have been added to `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`.

Comment: `Performance.class` works

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem with the same example :)